# recover data from partition unable to mount

Tags: debian, data-recovery

**One partition of corrupt hard drive can't be mounted**

What does it mean, if one partition of a hard drive with error can't be mounted while all others are mounted? (Especially the first, boot partition can be mounted, means the partition table should be available.)

**Recover from unmountables**

And i'm having trouble to recover the partition, if i can't mount it. Which tool exists for Debian, (maybe in forensics-all) to recover data from a non-mountable disk / partition?

Which tools don't work:
dd
dc3dd
extundelete
gddrescue (gnu ddrescue)
myrescue

```
if mounted:
ddrescue: Can't open input file: No such file or directory

if not mounted:
ddrescue: Can't open input file: Permission denied
```

https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/forensics-all

**Mount error**

```
/dev/sdc1 at /media/data: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/data"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Comment: dd/ddrescue are intended to make copies of the data before you try to repair things.

Comment: Make a copy with `dd` then perform a `fsck` on the copy.

Comment: "make a copy" did not work... thats why I asked this confusing question. But it didn't work because of running the commands without root rights... Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both dd and gddrescue are able to recover data from non-mountable images. The reason of the error message is the missing of the root rights. You need to run dd or ddrescue as root.